# pthread Library location

Tags: pthreads

In which directory does the libpthread library reside on a Linux system ?

Comment: Hi - your question refers to a generic "Linux system" - this is a bit too vague to answer clearly. Could you please specify which OS/arch you are referring to ?

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of ways to find this out.

Simply type `find / -name 'libpthread.so' -print` to find the file named `libpthread.so` on your system.

You can check the library locations your dynamic linker `ld` checks in for libraries, which are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Also, if you are running a debian-based distro, or have `dpkg` installed, you can use `dpkg -S libpthread`, which will give you the packages that contain files with the name libpthread and where those files are installed. Distros with RPM support should have a similar feature. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following command = `locate libpthread.so`

it gave the following output when I tried :

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Oracle Linux OS 6.8, you can run the following command:

```
ldconfig -p | grep pthread.so
```

Sample output:

```
libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
libgpgme-pthread.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpgme-pthread.so.11
```

Answer (score 2):

The pthreads run time library usually lives in /lib, while the development library usually lives in /usr/lib.  This can vary by distribution, but this is at least the location on Debian and Ubuntu and I doubt other mainstream distributions use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu it is located in `usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.
At least, it is the path on my system!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way:

```
ldd /bin/tar | grep pthread
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f803cdd4000)
```